# How can I handle async calls when validating with Backbone.js (uniqueness specifically)

Tags: validation, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

This is relevant for either client or server side apps using backbone. I am attempting to create a validation function with uniqueness checks to MongoDB or some REST call (depending on environment). Both of these calls are async by nature; however, I think I actually need to make it block here for validation purposes. If I don't return anything the validate function will assume validation passed.

My code currently looks like this on the server side:

```
isUnique: function (key) {
    var dfdFindOne = this.findOne({key: this.get(key)}),
        dfd = new Deferred();
    dfdFindOne.done(function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        dfd.resolve(true);
    });
    return dfd;
};
```

... some stuff here....
I feel like I can do some sort of wait till done functionality here before I return... perhaps not though. I wish backbone provided a callback function or something or accepted some sort of deferred type thing.

```
validate: function() {
    var result = undefined;
    if(!this.isUnique(key).done(function(){
       result = "AHHH not unique!";
    });
    return result;
}
```

A possible solution might be to force mongodb's native node client to call things synchronously. I think I can do the same with rest calls... This is probably a bad solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call the ajax request and set async:false in this way the return will have value. However to use async:false is evil because could appear as the browser is locked. For server side maybe there are not always workarounds for set async: false

My recommendation is to use your own validation flow instead of Backbone.validate flow, because the validation flow of Backbone was made thinking for synchronous validations only. You could try something like this:

```
//Code in your Model
isUnique: function (callback) {
    var dfdFindOne = this.findOne({key: this.get(key)});
    dfdFindOne.done(function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        callback(result);
    });
};
validate: function(callback) {
    this.isUnique(callback);
}

//trying to validate before save
model.validate(function(result){
  if( result == 'whatexpected'){
     model.save();
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution; however, I believe in the docs it mentions that validate gets called when using "set" as well, which means I'd either need to override set, or use alternate method and call set, which might result in some confusion. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I know that validate will be called in the set, but because our new validate does not return anything for Backbone it means that validate(in their flow) is ok. My workaround does not have conflicts with Backbone. Check "If the attributes are valid, don't return anything from validate; if they are invalid, return an error of your choosing."

Comment: If you feel comfortable you could call the new validate with other name, like customValidate, and call model.customValidate(function(result){ but the important thing is that for async behavior we do not need to invent the wheel, the common solution are the callbacks. =)

Comment: I suppose I can't think of many other cases other than unique-ness that require async. All of this would get skipped on set. I suppose on save on the client side I can force async to be false, which only leaves server side as an issue. I guess set doesn't really matter there since most of the time we immediately set then save, which means I can mess with save however I wish... Fair enough :). Thanks!